# Does an Official LGBT Manifest exist?

Tags: lgbt+

The gender ideology comes with several definitions, concepts, or "ideas" for (I think, in this chronological order):

- Biological sex,
- Sexual orientation,
- Sexual identity
- Sexual expression,

among their ideological derivations.

Because several rights are claimed to be missing in the society regarding these new terms, I am having a doubt, maybe trivial for the LGBT people, but I am sure not trivial for somebody looking for a clear definition.

Because new laws are being requested and introduced in several countries, using these terms, I am asking where the formal definitions for these concepts are formulated.

My question is: Is there a formal, official manifest, baseline, reference or document from which we could find a definition for the gender ideology concepts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. LBGT isn't an "ideology," it's a term that encompasses a set of gender identities and sexual orientations. I'm also unfamiliar with what Gender Ideology is; are you talking about gender studies, which is a humanities or social science field? Regardless, neither LBGT people nor gender studies scholars comprise a group sufficiently homogeneous to have a manifesto as such.

Comment: Regardless, questions about definitions might not be on-topic here, and this particular one might also be a bit too broad.

Comment: Maybe it is not so broad, but studies and laws are being requested in some countries involving the terms indicated (without clear definitions?). I am not asking for the definitions, obviously that is not the question focus. I am asking if that kind of manifest or "declaration of terms" do exist. Easily, the question should be yes or no, or maybe yes, subject to...

Comment: I'm not quite sure who you'd expect to make a manifesto. It's not as if LBGT people all belong to some group that sets definitions. There might be various LBGT-rights groups with somewhat overlapping definitions, but even they won't necessarily agree.

Comment: Neither I. That is why I am asking :).

Comment: I mean, there isn't a Jewish manifesto, a black manifesto, or a women's manifesto, except perhaps as the opinion of individuals from those groups. Why would there be an LBGT manifesto?

Comment: I am not clear, again. Perhaps the answer is no, as per your view, and that is that i wish to confirm in here. Israel defines itself as "Jewish and democratic state" and through the "Law of Return". Black people, based on the skin color, is a race; genetics is questioning the "race" concept. And woman (biological sex) is an undeniable condition. But "orientation", "expression" are rather fuzzy and subjective.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're saying a bit better now. You're not suggesting that LBGT people all follow or promote a particular ideology; you're wondering whether the various terms describing gender and gender identity have their root in a common source work? Is that what you're asking? If this is what you're saying, maybe you could edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes. Which is bad not in terms of gender studies, which could be ok with an evolving definition, but with legal rights over a concept which maybe would not be clear for everybody.

Answer (score 8):

I feel safe from contradiction if I were to declare that there is no "LGBT manifesto".

The "gender ideology" dialogue tends to refer to the transgender and [intersex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) parts of LGBT+, and not the LGB parts.  Nobody reasonably considers intersex people an ideology---these people undeniably exist, although they usually don't advertise being intersex.  So I'll focus on the transgender part.

Possibly the most recognized document among transgender people is the ***WPATH Standards of Care*** ([link](https://wpath.org/publications/soc)), which describes medical best practices in the treatment of transgender people:

> The  overall  goal  of  the  SOC  is  to  provide  clinical  guidance  for  health  professionals  to  assist  transsexual, transgender, and gender nonconforming people with safe and effective pathways to achieving lasting personal comfort with their gendered selves, in order to maximize their overall health,  psychological  well-being,  and  self-fulfillment.

This is written by a large international team of medical professionals who are specialized in the treatment of transgender patients.  To my knowledge, most of this team are non-transgender themselves.

This document contains a glossary containing two definitions similar to those listed:

> **Gender identity**:  A person’s intrinsic sense of being male (a boy or a man), female (a girl or woman), or an alternative gender (e.g., boygirl, girlboy, transgender, genderqueer, eunuch) (Bockting, 1999; Stoller, 1964).
>
> **Gender  role  or  expression**:    Characteristics  in  personality,  appearance,  and  behavior  that  in  a  given  culture and historical period are designated as masculine or feminine (that is, more typical of the male or  female  social  role)  (Ruble,  Martin,  &  Berenbaum,  2006).  While  most  individuals  present  socially  in  clearly  male  or  female  gender  roles,  some  people  present  in  an  alternative  gender  role  such  as  genderqueer or specifically transgender. All people tend to incorporate both masculine and feminine characteristics in their gender expression in varying ways and to varying degrees (Bockting, 2008).

A LGBT+ group GLAAD also has a [glossary of terms](https://www.glaad.org/reference/transgender):

> **Gender Identity**    A person's internal, deeply held sense of their gender. For transgender people, their own internal gender identity does not match the sex they were assigned at birth. Most people have a gender identity of man or woman (or boy or girl). For some people, their gender identity does not fit neatly into one of those two choices (see non-binary and/or genderqueer below.) Unlike gender expression (see below) gender identity is not visible to others.
>
> **Gender Expression** External manifestations of gender, expressed through a person's name, pronouns, clothing, haircut, behavior, voice, and/or body characteristics. Society identifies these cues as masculine and feminine, although what is considered masculine or feminine changes over time and varies by culture. Typically, transgender people seek to align their gender expression with their gender identity, rather than the sex they were assigned at birth.
>
> **Sexual Orientation**    Describes a person's enduring physical, romantic, and/or emotional attraction to another person. Gender identity and sexual orientation are not the same. Transgender people may be straight, lesbian, gay, bisexual, or queer. For example, a person who transitions from male to female and is attracted solely to men would typically identify as a straight woman.

Generally, transgender activists push for political goals that most members of society take for granted: to be treated with basic human dignity in everyday life [school, work, etc.], no sterilization requirements to participate in society, to be able to get married, to use public bathrooms without fear of being attacked, arrested, insulted, etc.

Their opponents tend to regard such political goals as going overboard and potentially dangerous, and thus pejoratively describe these goals as "gender ideology".